# How to fix document.update() not return new document

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a Product model with property: `{ _id, name, code }`

I have a product document:

```
{ "5d2eece48d04bc796b51d07d", "old name", "old code" }
```

I want to update my product document with `{ "5d2eece48d04bc796b51d07d", "new name", "new code" }` and return new document when finished. But it's not working, it's return old document.

I do not want use `Product.findByIdAndUpdate()` because it's run longer than `product.update()`.

Can you help me?

```
const upTest = async (id, updatedProduct) => {
    let { name, code} = updatedProduct
    try {
        let product = await Product.findById(id)
        const query = {
            ...(name && {name}),
            ...(code && {code}),
        }
        product.update(query)
        return product
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for the `update()` to complete and `update()` doesn't have an option to return the updated document.

use `findByIdAndUpdate`

If you don't do anything with the document before you return it there is no need for it to be an async function  just return the operation and handle the errors when you call the function

```
const upTest = (id, updatedProduct) => {
  const { name, code } = updatedProduct;
    const query = {
      ...(name && { name }),
      ...(code && { code })
    };
    return Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, query, { new: true });
};
```